# DocumentListener in seq diagram

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

I'm working on creating creational sequence diagram for applications, what I mean is a sequence diagram of the start of the execution of the program from the time it starts until the program is waiting for the user action, and I have two questions:

1- If I'm initializing listeners classes (like DocumentListener in Java), do I have to include them in the sequence diagram?

2- What would be a suitable starting up event? Can it be "application starts", and this event will create the class which has the main method?

Comment: Relating to the first question: You can include them as method calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554570/how-to-represent-listeners-in-uml-sequence-diagram

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9955503/2626313